# Replacing www.somoto.com with www.google.com in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

For some reason, when I hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> in Firefox (6.0.2) to open a new tab, it opens this website, `www.somoto.com`, even though I configured it to open `www.google.com` when I open a new tab.

I don't know what `www.somoto.com` is.

Does anyone know what that website is, and how to get Firefox to start off with Google instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the add-ons you have installed within Firefox. It might be one of those that changes your start page. [This](http://forums.cnet.com/7723-6122_102-518743.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I didn't find the apps it mentionned, but removing one fishy-looking add-on and restarting Firefox solved the issue.